# How do I store and retrieve signing credentials for IdentityServer4 deployed to Kubernetes?

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, identityserver4

I'm in the process of implementing IdentityServer4 into my ASP.NET Core web application, which will be deployed to a Kubernetes cluster using Continuous Deployment.

The documentation talks about adding signing credentials (`AddSigningCredential`) and most tutorials/guides demonstrate how to use this by loading a `.pfx` file from the file system, or by using the local certificate store and searching by the subject name.

Is there a commonly accepted way of storing, retrieving and rotating the signing credentials when deployed to a Kubernetes cluster with minimal intervention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a secret is the best option in Kubernetes.
K8s have a secret kind that can be deployed with other  ressource, here is a link to the official doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/
Or you could also use another secret manager , like Vault.
If I am not mistaken , I think it's the best practice.